# Mongodb PHP driver: how to create database and add user to it?

Tags: php, mongodb

so using the mongodb shell, I was able to create a database and add a username and password to it. How can I do the same in php? I have everything installed and able to connect to mongodb server.

However, I can't find any information in [the doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not believe `addUser()` is implemented in the PHP driver.

However, there is an [`execute`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) that should allow you to do an `addUser()` the same way you would from the mongo shell:

EDIT: After testing, I couldn't get [`execute`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) to do what you wanted, but I did find that the following works:

```
<?php
  // open connection
  $mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://" . MONGO_USER . ":" . MONGO_PASS . "@" . MONGO_HOST, array("persist" => "abcd1234"));
  $db = $mongo->selectDB("admin");

  // user info to add
  $username = "testUser";
  $password = "testPassword";

  // insert the user - note that the password gets hashed as 'username:mongo:password'
  // set readOnly to true if user should not have insert/delete privs
  $collection = $db->selectCollection("system.users");
  $collection->insert(array('user' => $username, 'pwd' => md5($username . ":mongo:" . $password), 'readOnly' => false));
?>
```

That adds a new user to the admin db on my server - checked via mongo shell after executing PHP script.

That said - why do you want to add a Mongo user from a PHP script?

Comment: but doesnt that only run Javascript? how would I inovoke mongo shell and add user....or are you saying adduser is implemented in the Javascript driver?

Comment: Every command you run inside the mongo shell is actually Javascript - see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/mongo+-+The+Interactive+Shell - `The MongoDB distribution includes bin/mongo, the MongoDB interactive shell. This utility is a JavaScript shell that allows you to issue commands to MongoDB from the command line.`  So, if `execute` allows you to pass arbitrary Javascript to the Mongo engine, then you should be able to use the same `addUser` command you used in the shell.  I'll test it on one of my Mongo installs shortly and report back.

Comment: Okay, can't seem to do it using `execute` although it's probably some mistake I'm making.  However, after digging around, I did find something that should work - see my edit above

Comment: is it possible to select a unique database and add user to that? basically I only want the user to have access to his/her own database only.

Comment: Sure, just use `$db = $mongo->selectDB("usersDatabaseNameGoesHere")` instead.  I haven't done it, but that's what the docs say: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-ConfiguringAuthenticationandSecurity

Comment: okay so I created a database called "testUsername" and collection "testUsername.system.user" which holds the username and password....but I cannot connect to this database as testUsername. Only authenticating as Admin, am I able to access this database.

Comment: ETWW-Dave can you confirm that it's not `username` but `user`?

Comment: I can confirm - the above is a cut/paste of the working code directly off my server that I used for testing.

Comment: This is not working anymore with newer mongodb versions (tested >= 3.0).

Answer (score 3):

A way to create a new mongodb user from PHP is via [MongoDB::command](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php):

```
//info to add
$db_name = 'db_name';
$db_user = 'new_user';
$db_pass = 'new_pass';

//autenticate with a user who can create other users
$mongo = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:root@localhost/admin");
$db = $mongo->selectDB( $db_name );

//command to create a new user
$command = array
(
    "createUser" => $db_user,
    "pwd"        => $db_pass,
    "roles"      => array
    (
        array("role" => "readWrite", "db" => $db_name)
    )
);

//call MongoDB::command to create user in 'db_name' database
$db->command( $command );
```

Tested with mongo 3.0 and PHP mongo driver 1.6