# Mongodb: created a database and added user to it, but cannot authenticate user

Tags: php, mongodb

this is the php code I used to add the user "someuser" to the "someusersdatabase".

```
<?
// open connection

  $mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://admin:passwd@remotemongoserver:27017");
  $db = $mongo->selectDB("someusersdatabase");

$mongo->selectDB("someusersdatabase")->createCollection('__tmp_collection_');
$mongo->selectDB("someusersdatabase")->dropCollection('__tmp_collection_');

 // $collections = $db->selectCollection("tmp");
 // $collections->insert(array('t' => '1'));

  // user info to add
  $username = "someuser";
  $password = "apassword";

  // insert the user - note that the password gets hashed as 'username:mongo:password'
  // set readOnly to true if user should not have insert/delete privs
  $collection = $db->selectCollection("system.users");
  $collection->insert(array('username' => $username, 'pwd' => md5($username . ":mongo:" . $password), 'readOnly' => false));
```

I can authenticate as admin, however when I authenticate someuser the log shows:

```
Mon Jun 27 14:01:38 [initandlisten] connection accepted from client:62708 #1
Mon Jun 27 14:01:38 [conn1] auth: couldn't find user someuser, someusersdatabase.system.users
```

but when I navigate to the web view, it displays both someusersdatabase and someusersdatabase.system.users

So is the user not being added properly? no error is being thrown when the php code runs...

Comment: this was the code provided by another user on SO on my previous question

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482224/mongodb-php-driver-how-to-create-database-and-add-user-to-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably [`call addUser()`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication#SecurityandAuthentication-ConfiguringAuthenticationandSecurity) instead of inserting directly into the collection, in case there's some under-the-hood bookkeeping going on and/or the hashing function is different.  Beyond that, the field name is `user`, not `username`.

Comment: It's not necessary to call `addUser` (inserting manually works as well), but the issue here is indeed the field name that should be `user` and not `username`.